# Disable BT pairing security pin on Embedded Linux device

Tags: linux, bluez

I have an embedded Linux board running a Yocto Linux image containing BlueZ.

I want to activate the HCI bluetooth device advertising mode and disable the pairing security.

I want to scan for the device with my smartphone and connect directly without security PI, just like any Audio device (JBL, ...).

I tried many methods using (bluetoothctl and other tools) but without success.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
Talel

Comment: You will need to configure a [profile](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/profile-api.txt) with `RequireAuthentication` set to false. There has just been a similar [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/135320/121848) over on raspberrypi stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

Set IOCapability of your device to NoInputNoOutput then pairing will happen but it won't ask for any confirmation similar to BT headsets.
bluetoothctl command line tool has option to set IOCapability. Set capability and check.

$bluetoothctl

[bluetooth]# power on

Changing power on succeeded

[bluetooth]# discoverable on

Changing discoverable on succeeded

[bluetooth]# pairable on

Changing pairable on succeeded

[bluetooth]# agent NoInputNoOutput
Agent registered

Comment: I tried your steps on my Linux host, and it still shows a PIN output to confirm in order to pair.